# Change file system of Eclipse for procedure/support of "New Web dynamic project"

Tags: java, .net, linux, eclipse, windows

I want to change file system of Eclipse for change "support" or "User interface" (UI) of **New Dynamic WEB Project**.

I have Windows 7 but I am interested also on Linux.
Should be easy change file system in Linux and not in Windows.

- **What do I would to change?**

In Eclipse, I press **NEW**-> **Dynamic Web Project**, put the name and press **Next**.
We have, in default, this window:
[image]

Now I have to remove `src` folder and put new folders `src\main\java` and `src\main\resource`.
So I will have a folder "Source Folders" of Maven project because I will convert in it.
So the result is:

[image]

**-** Why not do **New Maven Project** so I will have these directory
   **java resource**.

Why I not like the pom.xml of **new Maven Project** that is in default:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>bla</groupId>
  <artifactId>bla</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>asd Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>bla</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Miss the plugin of maven:

```
<build>
      <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
              <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
              <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>

      </build>
```

If I do, from project **Dynamic WEB project** and will convert to **Maven Project**. I will have this **pom.xml** that is generated from Eclipse:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>HibernateExample</groupId>
  <artifactId>HibernateExample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>HibernateExample</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <build>
  <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

  </build>
</project>
```

For me like too the second **pom.xml** and not get error of miss plugin maven.
So today I've got an idea:

- **Why not change the program files (say inside folder Eclipse) and change line of folder " Source
  Resource"?**

So I will have the new default windows (see second image) in every time when I create Dynamic WEB Project.

I hope the title is correct.

Comment: I guess you need to clarify your question.

Comment: Is acceptable the question, now?